# Callback function in freeglut from object

Tags: c++, opengl, callback, freeglut

I'm using MSVC++ and freeglut in order to use openGL. Now, I have a class called `Camera`, which is pretty simple, but it also holds the function for the reshaping of my window.

My question is: how can I set `glutReshapeFunc(void (*callback)(int,int))` to my function in my camera?

I have the following code, which won't work, because of a compiler error:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Camera *camera = new Camera();
    glutReshapeFunc(camera->ReshapeCamera);
}
```

and my Camera class looks like this in *Camera.h*:

```
class Camera
{
public:
    Camera(void);
    ~Camera(void);
    void ReshapeCamera(int width, int height);
};
```

Maybe this is just a more general callback question, but the only thing I found on the internet was creating some wrapper class around the callback. But it doesn't look like this should be so hard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no clean way to do this. C does not know about objects, so pointers-to-members don't work. C does not do templates, so functors don't work. The API does not even allow you to pass an arbitrary `void *userData` to your callback, so you can't pass the object around in that way either.

So, indeed, you'll have to create a wrapper function that is not a member function, and you'll have to give it access to the `Camera` object instance somehow, through a static and/or global variable.

If there can be multiple objects listening for this event, you could create a singleton class that allows you to register arbitrary listeners.

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect it directly. ReshapeCamera is a member function, it needs a camera instance in order to run. The glut callback is a C function, which don't have an instance of camera to call your method. You need to create a function that call the camera reshape method.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with a "C vs C++" thing. You just need to understand what a member function call entails and basically what it compiles down to.

```
myObject.memberFunction(); // This is what the programmer sees.
memberFunction(&myObject); // This is what the compiler sees.
```

A member function is a fancy description of a function that simply takes the object as a first parameter. It's just invisible in the actual parameter list.

```
void MyClass::memberFunction() // This is the declaration the programmer sees.
void memberFunction(MyClass* this) // This is what the compiler sees.
```

From there, C++ adds special semantics to make it easy to work in an object-oriented fashion. So, even though your object has a member function of the format void(int, int), it actually has the format void(Camera*, int, int), and that does not match the desired format! This is why static function members *can* be used for such function pointers. Ever notice that static member functions cannot access the members of "this"? That is because static member functions do *not* pass an instance of the object representing "this".

In effect, you could emulate much of object-oriented programming in plain C. If you make a set of functions that take a struct pointer as the first parameter, you gain many of the same advantages!

Comment: So I created a static function in my class now, but it seems that it cannot convert from __thiscall to __decl. `Error 1 error C2664: 'glutReshapeFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall Camera::* )(int,int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int)'`. And adding an explicit __cdecl gives a warning about the `Camera::`-part.

Comment: @Marnix: The `__thiscall` suggests to me that `glutReshapeFunc` is not declared as `static`.

Comment: @Thomas: No the glutReshapeFunc is probably a function in C, the function coming from my Camera class is static, but has therefore another namespace. So it doesn't seem to get this.

Comment: glutReshapeFunc(Camera::ReshapeCamera);

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates how to register a c callback function from c++
Its generally useful, not specific to glut.

Here is your client c++ program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

std::cout << "launching Camera ..." << std::endl;

Camera * camera = new Camera();

// ------ glut new window boilerplate ------- //

int WindowHandle = 0;
glutInit(&argc, argv);
WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow("hello there");
if(WindowHandle < 1) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window" << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// ------------------------------------------ //

camera->setup_callback();

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
```

}

Here is the Camera.cpp

```
Camera * ptr_global_instance = NULL;

extern "C" void ReshapeCamera_callback(int width, int height) {
    // c function call which calls your c++ class method
    ptr_global_instance->ReshapeCamera_cb(width, height);
}

void Camera::ReshapeCamera_cb(int width, int height) {
    std::cout << "width " << width << " height " << height << std::endl;
}

void Camera::setup_callback() {
    // c++ method which registers c function callback
    ::ptr_global_instance = this;
    ::glutReshapeFunc(::ReshapeCamera_callback);
}
```

and its header Camera.h

```
class Camera {
public:
    void ReshapeCamera_cb(int width, int height);
    void setup_callback();
};
```

Notice the use of a c++ global class pointer ptr_global_instance