# libcurl callbacks w/c++ class members

Tags: c++, libcurl

Taken from the [libcurl programming tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) on the libcurl site:

> libcurl with C++
>
> There's basically only one thing to keep in mind when using C++
>   instead of C when interfacing libcurl:
>
> The callbacks CANNOT be non-static class member functions
>
> Example C++ code:
>
> ```
> class AClass 
> {   
>     static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,   void ourpointer)       
>     {   /* do what you want with the data */   }  
> }
> ```

What is this limitation for, is it a problem of scope? If each class member has it's own easy_handle then can it then use callbacks to it's own non static member functions? It doesn't go on to say. I can work with this either way, but I'm curious why it exists.

edit: One more thing; does this impose a limitation on creating easy_handle's from within a class? That would greatly pose a problem for my design if so, I'd like each object to have its own easy_handle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a C++ class member function as a C callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000663/using-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-c-callback-function)

Comment: See also: [Callback to non-static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067498/callback-to-non-static-method), [Callback function in freeglut from object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008266/callback-function-in-freeglut-from-object), [Cast member function for create_pthread() call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826620/cast-member-function-for-create-pthread-call)

Answer (score 3):

A non-static member function is normally not allowed as a C callback because it needs also the instance pointer as a hidden parameter, which is not provided by the calling C code (and this hidden parameter, depending from the compiler, may not be passed according to the "regular" calling convention, but in a particular register, ...).

Static member functions, instead, are "normal" functions with a particular scope (which is not relevant as far as the ABI is concerned).

Answer (score 1):

To call an instance method, you need an instance to call it on. The libcurl functions that take function pointers don't also take object pointers (rather, can't, since they're C functions), so there's no way of passing the requisite data to call an instance method.

You can pass an instance pointer via the `userdata` argument, then use that to invoke an instance method:

```
class AClass {
public:
    static size_t invoke_write_data
        (void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* pInstance)       
    {
        return ((AClass*)pInstance)->write_data(ptr, size, nmemb);
    }

    size_t write_data(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb) {
        /* ... */
    }
};

...
    extern AClass instance;

    curl_easy_setopt(easy_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, AClass::invoke_write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(easy_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &instance);
```

If you need to pass more data via the `userdata` argument, use a struct that includes the instance pointer as a member. Be careful about memory management: the argument struct could end up leaking or being reclaimed early.

When C++0x becomes standard and supported by compilers, you should be able to make use of closures to bind an instance and instance method, passing an anonymous function as the callback.

See also: "[How do I pass a pointer-to-member-function to a signal handler, X event callback, system call that starts a thread/task, etc?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2)" from the C++ FAQ.